# About creating a 3D fancy box

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

Dear community members,

I want to draw a 3D fancy box by coupling the first box (wich has a simple rectangle) and the second one. Have you any ideas?

[image]
These are the Latex codes for the first and the second boxes, respectively.

First code (written outside the \begin{document} environment):

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\xdefinecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{1475bb} % Neutral Blue
\colorlet{bancolor}{mycolor}

\def\bancolor{mycolor}
\newenvironment{mybox}[3][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]%
    \def\myboxname{#3}%
    \node [draw, line width=0.5mm, inner sep=1.5ex,text width=#2]% good 
options: minimum height, minimum width  , fill={mycolor!30}
    (BOXCONTENT) \bgroup\rule{0pt}{3ex}\ignorespaces
}{%
\egroup;
\node [right,inner xsep=1em,fill=bancolor!50,outer sep=0pt,text 
height=2ex,text depth=.5ex, text =black, font=\bf] (BOXNAME) 
at ([shift={(-1em,0pt)}]BOXCONTENT.north west) {\myboxname};
\fill[bancolor] (BOXNAME.north east) -- +(-1em,1em) -- +(-1em,0) -- cycle;
\fill[bancolor] (BOXNAME.south west) -- +(1em,-1em) -- +(1em,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

I call it inside the \begin{document} environment as follows:

```
\begin{mybox}{\textwidth}{Title}
    \justifying
    Hello World!
\end{mybox}
```

Second code (written within the \begin{document} environment):

```
\smartdiagramset{
    uniform color list=gray!60!black for 2 items,
    back arrow disabled=true,
}
\smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{PGF}
```

Regards.
Widad

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The `tcolorbox` package might interests you.

Comment: Some feedback would be nice...

Comment: Christian Hupfer, thank you for your prompt reply! I discovered the tcolorbox package, it's amazing! Best regards.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an implementation with `tcolorbox` and `TikZ`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{bluebg}{rgb}{0.5,0.7,0.84}
\definecolor{trianglebg}{rgb}{0.09,0.41,0.69}


\makeatletter
\tcbset{%
  decorationwidth/.store in=\kv@decoration@width,
  decorationwidth=10pt,
  boxedtitlecolor/.colorlet=tcbcol@boxedtitle,
  decorationcolor/.colorlet =tcbcol@decorationcolor,
  decorationcolor=trianglebg,
  boxedtitlecolor=bluebg,
}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{myboxother}[2][]{%
  enhanced, sharp corners,
  drop shadow,
  attach boxed title to top left={xshift=-\kv@decoration@width,yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
  coltitle=black,
  boxed title style={toprule=0pt,bottomrule=0pt,leftrule=0pt,frame hidden,enhanced,colback=tcbcol@boxedtitle,sharp corners},
  underlay boxed title={ 
    \coordinate (refpointsouth) at ($(title.south west)+(0pt,0mm)$);
    \filldraw[line width=0pt,tcbcol@decorationcolor] 
    (refpointsouth)  -- ($(refpointsouth) + (\kv@decoration@width,0)$) -- +(0pt, -\kv@decoration@width) -- cycle;
    \coordinate (refpointnorth) at ($(title.north east)-(\kvtcb@left@rule-0.25pt,0pt)$);
    \filldraw[line width=0pt,tcbcol@decorationcolor]
    (refpointnorth)  -- ($(refpointnorth) + (-\kv@decoration@width,0pt)$) -- ($(refpointnorth) +(0pt, \kv@decoration@width)$) -- cycle;
    }
  ,
  title={#2},#1,  
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{myboxother}[decorationwidth=15pt]{My title}
  Hello World

  \blindtext
\end{myboxother}


\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,interior style={top color=white,bottom color=white!60!black}, drop shadow]
  Hello World
  \blindtext
\end{tcolorbox}

or a small box

\tcbox[enhanced,interior style={top color=white,bottom color=white!60!black}, drop shadow south]{Hello World}

\end{document}
```

[image]